# JavaScript requires error on WordPress 6.3

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, php-7.4

I'm a WordPress beginner. My WordPress version is 6.3. Due to some reason I had to change the website URL, after that the website is not running smoothly. Elementor is not loading at all when I tried to edit a page, default WordPress editor also not loading. I'm getting a JavaScript error in different areas eg: `The Site Health check requires JavaScript.`, `The Theme Installer screen requires JavaScript.` Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say "change the website URL" do you mean you had to host the website on a different domain? Or you mean you had to change the permalinks structure?

Comment: have you enabled javascript in your browser setting ?

Comment: Host in a different domain

Comment: Yes, Javascript is enabled already.

Comment: It really seems javascript is disabled in your browser. Did you alteady try loading the page in a different browser?